# Using return or next after calling res.redirect

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to write a code for redirecting all my `Http` requests to `Https`, now I wanted to ask I have seen below code on many different websites but some of them use `return` with `res.redirect`, some use `return` `after` `res.redirect`, some don't use anything and some use only `next()` `after` `res.redirect`.

I just want to ask what is the use of `return` or calling `next()` here. Or am I missing anything here ??

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    if(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "http") {
        console.log('Request was HTTP');
        /* return ??*/ res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
        // return or next() or nothing ??.
    } else {
        console.log('Request was not HTTP');
        return next();
    } 
});
```

Comment: since you are using `if/else` you don't _need_ the return. But many developers always use a return to make it clear that the code is finished and to prevent other code from accidentally running. Since your code does nothing after your conditional, then return is not _needed_. But you should probably never call `next` after doing a `res.redirect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next()` is a part of Express middleware. It tells to execute the next middleware function on the functions flowchart. If its not used the next middleware will not be executed.

`return` is used just to ensure that the execution stops after triggering the callback i.e no part of callback is processed again whether you use it with `next` or `redirect` it has same use to stop the execution of that particular function.

Comment: What about return with res.redirect ??

Comment: Same thing, to be confirmed that it will exit the function along with redirect

Comment: The answer should be clear and exhaustive. This answer is not that kind.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect. redirect does not return a value. Therefore you do not need the return in the code. Your function will implicitly `return undefined` when it goes out of scope.  The rules are pretty simple for middleware. You can response to the request, to do something, and then pass on control by calling next()

Answer (score 4):

In general, I do recommend to use:

```
return res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
```

due to in this case you explicitly return the redirect response.

In most case just `res.redirect()` is enough and you do have a redirect response (HTTP 302), but an error may appear in your server log especially if you use it inside `async (req, res) => {}` function.

Comment: I don't know why, my app is working perfectly on my machine but error something like this `cannot set status after sent to user` in my linux server. I use `return res.status(200).redirect('/')`. Is my redirect ok ? or what may cause the error ?

Comment: @PhilipPurwoko No. You redirect is not correct. Please see my answer above. redirect has status 301 or 302 but not 200.